# Receiver has no segue with identifier - even though segue exists in storyboard - Xcode 8, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, segue

I've added a segue from a view controller through a navigation controller to another view controller. I'm trying to call performSegueWithIdentifier but I'm running into this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver
>   () has no segue with
>   identifier 'toLogin'

The code that I'm using is:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLogin", sender: self)
```

Here's my setup (with the segue selected):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no navigation controller in your storyboard for initial view instead of having navigation controller for login controller embed your initial view controller with navigation controller.

Comment: that didn't solve the error - it still occurs randomly.